# Unable to add desired capabilities for remote web driver

Tags: selenium, grid, remotewebdriver

I am unable to compile my code when I try to add the following to enable selenium node on my machine.

```
URL hubUrl = new URL("");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.LINUX);
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(hubUrl, capabilities);
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you forgot to add the Hub url.
Try this:

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

or another variant:

```
URL hubUrl = new URL("http://hubIP:hubPort/wd/hub");
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.LINUX);
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(hubUrl, capabilities);
```